# How can I get scroll-margin to work mobile HTML?

Tags: html, css, mobile, anchor

I'm trying to get anchors to scroll to the right place in iPhone versions of Safari, Firefox, and Chrome (EDIT: all up to date with the latest version). Scroll-margin is working for this for firefox & chrome on my Linux desktop -- even in mobile developer mode. But when I'm on my iPhone in any of these browsers and I click on these links, the header covers up my anchor text, which it doesn't on desktop (is this working in Android? I wouldn't be stunned it if were). Is this a bug in scroll-margin? Check out this simple example.

```js
function toTop() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  line-spacing: 2;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.stuff {
  padding: 15px;
}

#top,
.here {
  padding: 30px 20px;
}

.here {
  scroll-margin: 70px 0 0 0;
  /* Just in case scroll-snap-margin is needed, see https://caniuse.com/#search=scroll-margin */
  scroll-snap-margin: 70px 0 0 0;
}

#topbtn {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  background: red;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class=sticky>Sticky header</div>
<div id=top><a href="#here">Link to here</a> <a href="#there">Link to there</a>
</div>
<div class=stuff>a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of
  text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br>  a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of
  text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br> a bunch of text<br>
</div>
<a class="here stuff" name=here>Here!</a>
<div class=stuff>a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more
  text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br>
  <a class=here name=there>There!</a><br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch
  more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br>  a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch
  more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br> a bunch more text<br>
</div>
<button id=topbtn onclick=toTop()>Top</button>
```

This code works on my desktop but the link scrolling isn't right on any iPhone mobile version of firefox or chrome or safari.

Why doesn't this work on mobile?

Edit: This snippet doesn't scroll right for me whether or not I comment out the line about scroll-snap-margin. See the note at canIuse [canIuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=scroll-margin)
PPS Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/chevvio/pen/LYGYxLJ) in case that makes testing easier, as at least on my phone, I don't see the code snippet on this page.

Comment: Hm... I'm a bit lost It's working perfectly on mobile for me. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Working perfectly for me too on my phone and desktop.

Comment: Hmm, for me on my iPhone versions of Firefox, Chrome, Safari, the anchor link doesn't scroll to the right place, whereas on desktop the anchor does scroll to the right place. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Are you two using Android? I just clarified my question, thanks.

Comment: Thanks @cloned for helping me get a code snippet. I was trying to get that to work without success! That said, I brought the codepen link back because code snippets on StackOverflow don't seem to work on mobile browsers, and that's essential to my question. Thanks again